# Javascript, crypto.subtle : how to import RSA private key?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, rsa

I generated using python a RSA key pair and I want to import it in javascript. I successfully import the public key but I'm struggling with the private key importation.

Python :

```py
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.generate(1024)
private_key = key.export_key().decode("ascii")
public_key = key.publickey().export_key().decode("ascii")
```

Javascript :

```js
function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

async function importRsaPublicKey(pem) {
  // fetch the part of the PEM string between header and footer
  const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
  const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
  const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
  // base64 decode the string to get the binary data
  const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
  // convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
  const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

  return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "spki",
    binaryDer,
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    true,
    ["encrypt"]
  );
}

async function importRsaPrivateKey(pem) {
  // Same logic as previous
  const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
  const pemFooter = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
  const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    
  const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
  const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

  return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "spki",
        binaryDer,
        {
          name: "RSA-OAEP",
          hash: "SHA-256"
         },
        true,
        ["decrypt"]
        );
    );
}
```

When I try to import the private key like this :

```js
var pem = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIICWwIBAAKBgQC1rayx8fyYUbyV5h/HtkIq3TBw5CZY8qKL4Kx5+gCLJj4ZklZ+6J6HU+OLGclLVoE7fwLPIJTRIG47kRG7eUG4rfmkXQJx4gOyBjOpfnE5GRDlXzUcymk5XOh87N1o0PGsfYm844PYZaU2MWiyvob717LlEELO4l7nxc11/oucTQIDAQABAoGARGd5W+CMZj90PY5RTe0qOaBhgkfsxlXI7NixqBWAyeOiwxcNuSfVtIdZ58BUQaj27JNUV+9hCOJojsX+wrMTkpaD1bmDEFibxuHOCuZQ/DszTmPNwx5INcR7wKhibbJA4rtzoHt2B8G/6mc0O+bJz6p0C4IJULTmiTvhuQULesMCQQDTZ/2zzO5sv4Z2Y2GD3RAoF+MhoYyR3Rt/36LsAmAWVQz12UIhqd0VzljEKNDUIFNHRU5GTcGSPvrBSNZbfTYPAkEA3ABfQ54KKoVQEcHNG6OI4QrA8PaQfCfVq1hMnbLoxJYRB9Fjfbs38uljJ6j6CqtQMfrrE7ZplpOXcW6FeXWD4wJAE0VJdRhbK4KR6TzJ6NE/5ce3ppspSyqSlSd3nHfi9mYuVkLFqnfndVNn+AmYb526uaZxqirwWDpxdSkEkTZqtQJAGU3ppytcW/utc/1ojA9JRSkpfA3AHKewSd8EIPddEo94MgABg4qvKr9xajRjXirKNJV5yHCowGsFdkSSEaBUpQJARQPMkQ7OWrlXLwICP9zUkPVJWkq2LSDZA1Rx3ySgbDD+VjrOo+1wtKmHuGf9QFxbqc50QT58OqrCDRWzq8BExw==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

var private_key = await importRsaPrivateKey(pem);
```

I got the following error :

> Syntax error
>
> Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.

Do you know how to correct this ?

EDIT :

I need to export the key as pkcs8 :

python :

```py
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.generate(1024)
private_key = key.export_key(pkcs=8).decode("ascii")
public_key = key.publickey(pkcs=8).export_key().decode("ascii")
```

and to import the key as pkcs8 not spki

javacript :

```js
async function importRsaPrivateKey(pem) {
  const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----";
  const pemFooter = "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

  const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);

  const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
  const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

  return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "pkcs8",
    binaryDer,
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    true,
    ["decrypt"]
    );
}
```

Comment: `spki` is for public keys. Try with `pkcs8`

Comment: Thanks for that, I still get an error : DataError

Comment: Your key is pkcs#1. You need to convert it to pkcs#8 format. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033786/how-can-i-import-an-rsa-private-key-in-pem-format-for-use-with-webcrypto/51035703#51035703

Comment: That's it ! Thanks !

Comment: Ok, I posted a summary as answer

Answer (score 7):

`spki` is used to import public keys. Change it to `pkcs8`

FYI, the header in your key, `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` means that your key is in PKCS #8 format. That is the form of key webcrypto can import.

If you had  `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, that would mean your key was serialized in PKCS#1 format.  And before calling importKey(), you would need to convert it to PKCS#8. See [How can I import an RSA private key in PEM format for use with WebCrypto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033786/how-can-i-import-an-rsa-private-key-in-pem-format-for-use-with-webcrypto/51035703#51035703)

Comment: To convert your key from PKCS1 to PKCS8, you can use ssl: `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in pkcs1.key -out pkcs8.key`

Comment: I am getting similar error -> DATA ERROR but I am using --- Begin Certificate --- and -- End Certificate -- in the header of the key I am importing. How can I fix this ?